# build family relationships between contacts in CRM projects

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, tree

i want to build family relationships between contacts ,and discover the hidden relaions between contacts and show it using recursion in sql server .
for example:
i have this table that contains :

```
User_id_1   User_id_2   relation
1           2           Parent-child
2           3           Brother-brother
3           4           Brother-brother
```

my stored procedure should discover all relation for specific user id.
if calling this sp with user_id=4,
it should give me all relation of user_id=4
and it should know than 4 is brother with 3 and 2 ,
and 1 is parent of 4 .
how i can do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You could start with 2 more tables, 1 to configure a relationship (akin to your current `relation` column) and another to configure which relationships to walk during the recursive lookup.

```
Table: Relationship
Id: int
Description: string

Table: RelationshipToRelationship
FromRelationshipId: int
ToRelationshipId: int
```

Data would look like this:

**Relationship**

```
Id   Description
==   ===============
1    Brother-Brother
2    Parent-Child
```

**RelationshipToRelationship**

```
FromRelationshipId   ToRelationshipId 
==================   ================
1                    1
1                    2
```

Will update with a viable query if/when I work it out

Problems I foresee:

- You've presented the simplest case (my brother's parent is my parent) but falls apart for other cases (my brother's child is not my child).
- Similar problem for labeling the relationship (You can label my brother's parent as `Parent-Child` to me, but your brothers child would need to be labeled `Brother-Brother-Parent-Child`).

All gets confusing very quickly. Would you not be better to maintain a direct relationship between each party that you wish to relate (ie, another 2 records in your table linking user 4 & 2 as Brother-Brother and 4 & 1 as Parent-Child)?

Comment: ok thx ,, but i want a recursive technique using function and Sps in sql server to get all relationships of specific user that what i want to know ?

Comment: i mean in first record that 1 is parent of 2 ,

Comment: the other record represent that 2 is brother to 3 and 3 is brother to 4 ,,

Comment: what i want to do in my Store procedure that when i call the stored procedure with 4 user id it will return all users that has relation with 4=>answer (1,2,3)

Comment: it should step throw table and give me all users id that connected to this user ?

Comment: @Haneen - I understand what you want to do, im just having a hard time implementing it :)